# Angularjs is sending null values to API, why?

Tags: c#, angularjs, rest, api

I am sending an id and a list from angular to C# web API, but it is received by null when debugging the method, without knowing the reason.

angular service

```
this.deletevacs = function (staffid, vacs) {
    return $http.post("/AssignUserToDepartmentapi/api/assignuser/deletevacs?staffid=" + staffid + '&vacs=' + JSON.stringify(vacs))
}
```

angular js

```
var result = DevExpress.ui.dialog.confirm("Are you sure want to delete vacations assigned employees ?", "Confirm changes");
        result.done(function (dialogResult) {
            if (dialogResult) {

                var promisePost = Assignments.deletevacs($scope.SelectedEmp1.staffkey, $scope.oldvacs);
                promisePost.then(function (pl) {
                    toastr.success("Successfully deleted");
```

C#

```
[HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage deletevacs(int staffid,int[] vacs)
    {
        try
        {
            obj.ExecNonQuery(string.Format("delete from HR_AssRole_Dep where staff_key={0} and Role=7 and Current_Flag=1 and VacMKey ={1}"
                           , staffid
                           , vacs));


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

any help, thanks in advance

new C#

```
[HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage deletevacs([FromBody] role r)
    {

                    obj.ExecNonQuery(string.Format("delete from HR_AssRole_Dep where staff_key={0} and Role=7 and Current_Flag=1 and VacMKey ={1}"
                              ,r.Staff_Key
                              , r.VacMKey));





        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

class

```
 public class role
{
    //public int Ass_Dep_Key { get; set; }
    public int Dep_Key { get; set; }
    public int Staff_Key { get; set; }
    public int Role { get; set; }
    public List<int> VacMKey { get; set; }
    public short SelfApprov { get; set; }
}
```

new angular

```
var deletevacssss = { Staff_Key: $scope.SelectedEmp1.staffkey, VacMKey: $scope.selectedvacs };

        var result = DevExpress.ui.dialog.confirm("Are you sure want to delete vacations assigned employees ?", "Confirm changes");
        result.done(function (dialogResult) {
            if (dialogResult) {



                var promisePost = Assignments.deletevacs(deletevacssss);
                promisePost.then(function (pl) {
                    toastr.success("Successfully deleted");
```

new angular service

```
this.deletevacs = function (deletes) {
return $http.post("/AssignUserToDepartmentapi/api/assignuser/deletevacs", deletes)
}
```

when i make a debug, the r object from role class get the staffkey from angular correctly but the list of vacmkey count by 0 ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing List of Integers to GET REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957785/passing-list-of-integers-to-get-rest-api)

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

Use `[FromUri]` attribute in your HttpPost method parameter since you are getting the value from the querystring in the Url.

Try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage deletevacs([FromUri]int staffid, [FromUri] int[] vacs)
{
    try
    {
    obj.ExecNonQuery(string.Format("delete from HR_AssRole_Dep where staff_key={0} and Role=7 and Current_Flag=1 and VacMKey ={1}"
               , staffid
               , vacs));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}
```

Solution 2:
Create an object that contains the staffId and vacs properties and assign it to the parameter. Add the `[FromBody]` attribute to before the object parameter. Then in your httpPost call, put the parameter inside the body of the request instead of the Url.

Google about the use of `[FromBody]` in webapi.

Solution 3:

Istead of using HttpPost, why not use HttpDelete method. It is clear in your problem that your intention is to delete records. In web API, you can use the HttpDelete attribute instead of HttpPost. To do this, change your attribute to HttpDelete from HttpPost, and in your paramter, you can just pass the [FromUri] int StaffId only and inside your API,  all the vacs record related that StaffId, you can delete programmatically in DB. When calling your API use the $http.delete endpoint method instead.

Comment: first of all, thanks lot for reply.   i tried the first solution , but now vacs returned 0 not "null", when i tried the second solution i got error 500 er[object object]. any idea

Comment: Try creating a class for the request body.

Comment: [HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage deletevacs([FromBody] VacsInfo vacs)
{
    try
    {
    obj.ExecNonQuery(string.Format("delete from HR_AssRole_Dep where staff_key={0} and Role=7 and Current_Flag=1 and VacMKey ={1}"
               , staffid
               , vacs));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}

Comment: Public Class VacsInfo { int StaffId {get;set;}, int[] vacs {get;set;} }

Comment: Instead of using HttpPost, why not use HttpDelete method. In your HttpDelete method, you can just pass the StaffId and all the vacs record related that StaffId, you can manipulate in web API and delete them programmatically in DB. So Instead of passing two parameters, you can pass one param which is the staffId.

Comment: [HttpDelete]
        public HttpResponseMessage deletevacs(role r)
        {
            try
            {
                obj.ExecNonQuery(string.Format("delete from HR_AssRole_Dep where staff_key={0} and Role=7 and Current_Flag=1 and VacMKey ={1}"
                               , r.Staff_Key
                               , r.VacMKey));


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {


            }
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            return response;
        }    still the problem exist .

Comment: Is VacMKey type of int[] or just int?

Comment: If you are only using two int parameters you can use the querystring in your endpoint calls. In your api code try this. [HttpDelete] public HttpResponseMessage deletevacs([FromUri] int staffId, [FromUri] int vacMKey) { **your code here**}

Comment: it is int [] vac

Comment: What is the data type of column "VacMKey" in your HR_AssRole_Dep table?

Comment: it is smallint .

Comment: Since it is a small int, then it can only contain one value right? However, in your code you are trying to pass an array of int using this syntax: int[] vacs. This is incorrect, instead use Int16 vacs. Is VacMKey a foreign key? See ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425389/c-sharp-equivalent-of-sql-server-datatypes

Comment: yes it is.  i tried to use int16[] or short[] but sill the value = null, but when i put [fromuri] it becomes 0, any idea, thanks

Comment: remove the "[]" in your Int16 data type. Adding open and close bracket such as this "[]" after your data type declaration will convert it to type array. Since you mentioned that it is a small int in DB, you should use Int16.

You should declare it like this:

Int16 vacs = 0;

Not like below

int16[] vacs = 0;

Comment: i made an update,please look at it in the upper page, i used the class

Answer (score 0):

you should pass the parameter values for post method in params property .

```
var data = {staffid: staffid, vacs:vacs};
    $http({
      url: "/AssignUserToDepartmentapi/api/assignuser/deletevacs",
      method: "POST",
      params: data
    })
```

---

or try this below way

```
var data = {staffid: staffid, vacs:vacs};
    $http.post("/AssignUserToDepartmentapi/api/assignuser/deletevacs", data ).then(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
    alert("success"); 
},function (data, status, headers, config) { 
    alert("error"); 
});
```

---

**API code should be like**

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage deletevacs([FromUri]int staffid, [FromUri] int[] vacs)
{

...

}
```