# How to specify path like /pets/{id} but with multiple ids?

Tags: api, rest, swagger

I want to create a path which accepts any number of IDs separated with commas. It should accept all the following:

```
GET /pets/1,2  # returns info about pets with ids 1, 2
GET /pets/4,10,12,124,2  # same, for pets with ids 4, 10, 12, 124, 2
```

The book "building apis you won't hate" gave me this idea.
How do I do that in swagger?

Comment: Please add more details about what exactly you are trying to achieve. Why do you need more than one id?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin to get info about multiple objects. See edit.

Comment: Use a query parameter and just repeat it: `GET /pets/id=4&id=10&id=12&id=124&id=2`

Comment: Related question (but not swagger specific): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541338/how-to-construct-a-rest-api-that-takes-an-array-of-ids-for-the-resources.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin that doesn't look neat

Comment: That's not neat, but most servers will interpret this as a list of values.

Answer (score 6):

Swagger 2.0 supports the [`collectionFormat`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#parameterCollectionFormat) parameter. From the [documentation](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#parameterCollectionFormat):

> Determines the format of the array if type `array` is used. Possible values are:
>
> - `csv`: comma separated values: `foo,bar`
> - `ssv`: space separated values: `foo bar`
> - `tsv`: tab separated values: `foo\tbar`
> - `pipes`: pipe separated values: `foo|bar`
> - `multi`: corresponds to multiple parameter instances instead of multiple values for a single instance `foo=bar&foo=baz`. This is valid only for parameters in "query" or "formData".
>
> Default value is `csv`.

An example of use can be seen on the [documentation](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#path-item-object-example):

```json
{
  "get": {
    "description": "Returns pets based on ID",
    "summary": "Find pets by ID",
    "operationId": "getPetsById",
    "produces": [
      "application/json",
      "text/html"
    ],
    "responses": { ... }
  },
  "parameters": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "in": "path",
      "description": "ID of pet to use",
      "required": true,
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "collectionFormat": "csv"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Will this capture `/pets/123` without any commas as an array with 1 element?