# What method is used to Get multiple Ids from postman using golang

Tags: go, methods

Here I want to fetch the multiple IDs from the postman and I'm confuse which  method (POST, GET, PUT, DELETE) should I have to use for this. From these IDs I have to retrieve the data from database.

Can I use `Get` method and using `query string` then the url will be

```
localhost:8080/name?ids=1,2,3,4
```

Can anyone please tell me that I'm thinking is right or not and If not, then  What should I have to used for this.

Comment: Rather than sending all the ids in the query string, have you considered sending them in the `body` and submitting it as a `POST` ? Since, you're going to be querying the database with those `ids`, I would prefer sending them in the body, and it won't expose them in the URL. You could make it look like `localhost:8080/names`, in the **request body** - `{"user_ids": [1, 2, 3, 4]}`

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna I don't I don't think that there is post method is used because we are getting the records.

Comment: `POST` is meant to store something and `GET` is to retrieve, however, `POST` is more secure in a way where _request payload is not logged by the server_.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna But here I want to retrieve the records sir thats why I'm telling this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to construct a REST API that takes an array of id's for the resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541338/how-to-construct-a-rest-api-that-takes-an-array-of-ids-for-the-resources)

Answer (score 1):

Surely you can do it `GET` method. And it depends on how you are dealing with the `ids`, the best way to do it would be sending the values as an array. Something like this

`localhost:8080/name?ids=[1,2,3,4]`

Then you can retrieve that ids with something like this:

```
ids := r.URL.Query().Get("ids")
log.Println(ids)
```

And you will get the data like this `[1,2,3,3]`, but again it depends on how you are dealing with the data.